# Office 64 Bit & IE 32 Bit & VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, office-interop, outlook-addin

I have installed office 64 bit and there is a html file which is having a vbscript that calls CreateOjbect method.
In IE 32bit i am getting error "ActiveX object cannot create object"
But in IE 64 bit it runs fine.
How can i make it run fine in 32 bit IE?

Comment: need. more. data. As far as I can see, you are using the CreateObject method on an object that is designed to be used as a 64-bit object. But we definately need more information and probably a code snippet or two to be sure.

Comment: I have registered the Redemption64.dll using regsvr32.exe
Am getting an error when trying to execute  Createobject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")

Answer (score 2):

You need to locate the 32bit binary of "Redemption.dll" and register it. It might come with the 32bit version of Office, but I don't really have any experience with this particular component.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by creating a wrapper exe which will run the code i wanted in 64 bit.

The problem is communication between 32 & 64 bit processes

http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Comment: The problem is you aren't selecting the right 32bit or 64bit cscript.exe. You could just run the script with the correct cscript/wscript and avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Hmm but I don't have control over it.
because am running the script from a page in IExplorer